# Access Vuex mutators in navigation guards

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I'm building an app with Laravel + VueJS. In order to restrict some routes, I use navigation guards. The problem is that I need to access Vuex mutators in order to know if the current user is logged in. The thing is that `store` is defined, but I cannot use the mutator from the router. I got this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined` but as I said, `store` is well defined. Does someone have an idea ? Thanks !

**routes**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import Hello from '@/components/Hello'
import Register from '@/components/Register'
import Login from '@/components/Login'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: Hello,
      meta: {
        showNavigation: true,
        requireAuthentication: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      component: Register,
      meta: {
        showNavigation: false,
        requireAuthentication: false
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      component: Login,
      meta: {
        showNavigation: false,
        requireAuthentication: false
      }
    }
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})
```

**store**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    access_token: null,
    expires_in: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    setToken (state, response) {
      state.access_token = response.body.access_token
      state.expires_in = response.body.expires_in + Date.now()
    },
    getToken (state) {
      if (!state.access_token || !state.expires_in) return null

      if (state.expires_in < Date.now()) this.commit('destroyToken')

      return state.access_token
    },
    destroyToken (state) {
      state.access_token = null
      state.expires_in = 0
    },
    isAuthenticated (state) {
      return this.commit('getToken') !== null
    }
  },

  actions: {
    getOauthToken (context, user) {
      var data = {
        client_id: 2,
        client_secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }

      Vue.http.post('oauth/token', data)
      .then(response => {
        context.commit('setToken', response)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import { store } from './store'

import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueResource)
Vue.use(VeeValidate)

Vue.http.options.root = 'http://codex.app'

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireAuthentication)) {
    console.log(store)
    console.log(store.commit('isAuthenticated'))
    if (!store.commit('isAuthenticated')) {
      next('/login')
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Comment: It's probably `this.commit` in your `getToken` and `isAuthenticated` mutators. Your mutations are doing too much, they should only change state and nothing else. `getToken` and `isAuthenticated` should be actions

Comment: Works fine, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when we commit mutations, it refers to change the state and ONLY the state.when you need more complex mutations to change the state, using actions instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)